# Expanding anonymous function into a string

Tags: string, matlab, scope, anonymous-function

I have a set of anonymous functions, and I want to convert them into strings. Normally I would just use `func2str`, but the problem is I want the variables and internal functions to be expanded out into their "true" values. The problem I'm running into is that MATLAB is keeping these by the names, but recognizing the values. Example

```
classdef Bclass

    properties
        equation
    end

    function obj = Bclass(inEquation, inValue)
        obj.equation = @(t,y) inEquation(t,y) * inValue;
    end

    function out = getStr(obj)
        out = func2str(obj.equation); 
    end
end
```

The problem is that the `func2str` call is outputting `@(t,y) inEquation(t,y) * inValue`, when I actually want it to output something like `@(t,y) t*y * 5`, if we had said `b = Bclass(@(t,y) t*y, 5)`.

Is there a way to retrieve these variable values from MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do this, but it could quickly become very difficult if your problem becomes any more complex than the example given above (i.e. more complicated anonymous functions, multiple nesting levels, etc.). You'll have to make use of the [`functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) function to get information on the function handle, and its behavior may change between releases. Additionally, you'll have to do quite a bit of string manipulation (using functions like [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html), and [`strrep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html), as I do below).

I've tried to include here the most general approach I could, allowing for the following possibilities:

- `inEquation` can be a non-anonymous function handle (i.e. `@times`).
- `inEquation` can simply be passed along as is without actually being invoked.
- `inEquation` can be called multiple times in the anonymous function.
- The input arguments to `inEquation` can be named differently than what it is invoked with in `obj.equation`.
- `obj.equation` can contain indexing operations.

First, we'll initialize some variables to mimic your example:

```
f1 = @(m, n) m*n;  % Note the different variable names, but it will still work
inEquation = f1;
inValue = 5;
f2 = @(t, y) inEquation(t, y)*inValue;  % Function constructed using workspace variables
```

Next, we'll get the function information for `f2`:

```
s = functions(f2);
varNames = fieldnames(s.workspace{1});
varValues = struct2cell(s.workspace{1});
out = s.function;
```

The `workspace` field holds the variable names and values that were used to construct `f2`, and the `function` field is the string you'd get by calling [`func2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/func2str.html) on `f2`. We'll also need to compute a few things so we can correctly parse opening and closing parentheses in `f2`:

```
openIndex = (out == '(');
closeIndex = (out == ')');
parenIndex = cumsum(openIndex-[false closeIndex(1:end-1)]).*(openIndex | closeIndex);
```

Now, we'll loop over the workspace variables, convert their values to strings (if possible), and replace them in `out`:

```
for iVar = 1:numel(varNames)

  name = varNames{iVar};
  value = varValues{iVar};

  if isa(value, 'function_handle')  % Workspace variable is a function handle

    value = func2str(value);
    callIndex = strfind(out, [name, '('])+numel(name);
    fcnParts = regexp(value, '@\({1}([^\)])*\){1}(\S)*', 'once', 'tokens');

    if isempty(callIndex)  % Function handle is not invoked
      if isempty(fcnParts)  % Non-anonymous function handle (i.e. @times)
        value = ['@' value];
      end
      out = strrep(out, name, value);
    elseif isempty(fcnParts)  % Invoked function handle (i.e. @times)
      out = strrep(out, name, value);
    else  % Invoked anonymous function handle
      for iCall = callIndex
        args = out(iCall+(1:find(parenIndex(iCall+1:end) == parenIndex(iCall), 1)-1));
        value = regexprep(fcnParts{2}, ...
                          strcat('(?<!\w)', strsplit(fcnParts{1}, ','), '(?!\w)'), ...
                          strsplit(args, ','));
        out = strrep(out, [name, '(', args, ')'], value);
      end
    end

  elseif isnumeric(value) && isscalar(value)  % Workspace variable is a numeric scalar
    out = strrep(out, name, num2str(value));
  end

end
```

And we get the desired result for `out`:

```
>> out

out =

@(t,y)t*y*5
```

Note that this will also work as expected with a non-anonymous function handle as well:

```
>> f1 = @times;
>> inEquation = f1;
>> inValue = 5;
>> f2 = @(t, y) inEquation(t, y)*inValue;

% Repeat above processing...

>> out

out =

@(t,y)times(t,y)*5
```

It will also work on some more complicated functions:

```
>> postVolt = @(g, V) -.05*g*(V+80);
>> preIdx = 5;
>> postIdx = 1;
>> index = 6;
>> obj.values = {};
>> f2 = @(t) postVolt(obj.values{preIdx}(index), obj.values{preIdx}(obj.voltIdx{postIdx}));

% Repeat above processing...

>> out

out =

@(t)-.05*obj.values{5}(6)*(obj.values{5}(obj.voltIdx{1})+80)
```

Comment: The new version is beautiful! However it seems that this version does not work for a specific example of mine: `@(t)postVolt(obj.values{preIdx}(index),obj.values{preIdx}(obj.voltIdx{postIdx}))`, where `postVolt = @(g, V) -.05*g*(V+80);`, and `preIdx`, `postIdx` are both numbers. This code outputs `'@(t)-.05*obj.values{5}(6*(obj.values{5}(6+80),obj.values{5}(obj.voltIdx{1}))'` instead of `'@(t)-.05*obj.values{5}(6)*(obj.values{5}(obj.voltIdx{1})+80)`. You certainly have helped more than enough, I just wanted to let you know in case you wanted to make it have no errors

Comment: @wjmccann: That's one of those "more complex" issues I was referring to. ;) The problem is the extra indexing in the anonymous function. The nested parentheses complicate searching for argument lists in function calls using `regexp`. Another approach to that is needed. I can probably take another stab at it later.

Comment: @wjmccann: New version! This one can handle your more complicated case now.